# Devise, When reseting the password, a FLASH notice is only made for matched emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

When I reset my devise password, if I enter an email in the User model, the page refreshes to show:

```
You will receive an email with instructions about how to reset your password shortly.
```

I would like to flash a message when the app can't find an email, so the user knows. How can I add a flash message when a user submits a password reset for an email not in the DB?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Devise should catch that under the "failure:invalid:" category in your locales file.

Mine is located in $APP_PATH/config/locales/devise.en.yml

"Take a look at our locale file to check all available messages. You may also be interested in one of the many translations that are available on our wiki:

[github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/I18n](http://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/I18n) "

Comment: Strange, it's there put not showing up while the success is showing up